# Differnce Between describe & desc in hive

Tags: hive

I find the executing time difference between desc & describe the table schema.
Displaying same O/P with different executions time

ex:
 **Desc tablenamne;
time 1.8 sec**

**describe tablename;
time 1.2 sec**

What happening at background??

Thanks in advance
Narendra

Comment: execute 'desc tableX' some 10 times, 'describe tableX' some 10 times. you can find up and downs in the query processing times. DESC is just an alias of DESCRIBE.

Comment: + ignore the first executed command, when you startup the hive CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

hive> **EXPLAIN** DESC table_name;

hive> **EXPLAIN** DESCRIBE table_name;

- both gives you the same abstract syntax Tree plan with no difference.
- Desc is just an alias of Describe
- when Describe is given, it will execute a simple query(not a disributed query) on your metastore_db.
- time variations either up or down is due to some jvm processes working in your bg, process utilizations.